# Pointwise limit and norm limit in a sequence space

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces, pointwise-convergence

I have a situation where $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ is a complete normed sequence space. A sequence $a_n$ is cauchy in it and its pointwise limit is zero vector. I have a doubt whether $\|a_n\|$ will also converge to zero or not.

Comment: True as long as coordinate maps are continuous on  this space.

Comment: Can you elaborate please